# Simple random sampling(expanding square of a sum)

Tags: probability, sampling-theory

I was doing simple random sampling without replacement and got stuck with this expression.
I think on RHS there should be a coefficient of 2 with the second term.

$$( \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ { n } y _ { i } ) ^ { 2 }= \ ( \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ { n } y _ { i } ^ { 2 } + \sum _ { i \neq j = 1 } ^ { n } y _ { i } y _ { j } ) $$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $y_i y_j$ and $y_j y_i$ are different terms if you expand the sum.  No need to $2$.

Comment: You would have a 2 factor if it was $\sum_{1 \le i < j \le n}$ instead. But with this indexation you do not since every term will be present twice (for example $i= 2, j= 4$ and $i=4, j= 2$).

Comment: Thanks for your help but still I am not getting this because I am considering yi as sample values which are some real numbers so when we do this with real numbers yiyj or yjyi should be same right?

Comment: They would be the same, but since for $n=2$ the sum will run two times, the term will be added twice, so the coefficient of $2$ will show up on its own.